# How many Bloodshots have there been before 1994?

Tags: valiant-comics

So I was reading *Bloodshot #0*. In that, they show that Bloodshot programs has been around throughout the 1970s, '80s, and '90s, and have been in many wars but in 1993 they want him to grow a conscience due to high levels of collateral damage. In 1994, they hire Rees to solve the problem, and they capture a dying soldier and put nanites on him to examine whether a soul can be captured for transfer. So, my question is, how many Bloodshots where there before the final one in 94?

[image: Comic showing a prior Bloodshot]

[image: The soldier having his body and soul harvested]

Comment: Could you [edit] this to be clearer? At the moment I'm not quite sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's left ambiguous, but I believe there was only ever one Bloodshot. [Angelo Mortalli](https://web.archive.org/web/20090310012538/http://wiki.valiantentertainment.com:80/index.php/Angelo_Mortalli) is stated to be the only success of Project Rising Spirit (due to his Harbinger power), with the events of *Bloodshot #0* showing how his psyche was changed to make him more than just a killing machine. The memories of many dead soldiers are given to him to provide a human perspective and conscience. The slightly differing depictions of Bloodshot in earlier times is showing how those memories are now tinged with his sense of who he is.

Slightly complicating the matter is that there are acknowledged "[Speedshots](https://web.archive.org/web/20090309235702/http://wiki.valiantentertainment.com:80/index.php/Project_Rising_Spirit)" before him that survived only days, and were deployed on combat missions. Those are not chronicled, and I believe are established to be different from the soldiers whose memories he gained.